# R: Delete element from multiple vectors if only present in a few vectors

Tags: r, vector

How can I delete elements from multiple vectors if they are only present in a few vectors.
For example if I have the following 2 vectors

```
> Text <- c("AB.txt", "B.txt", "C.txt")
> Text2 <- c("B.txt", "C.txt")
```

Then I try to delete all elements with an 'A' using grep:

```
> Text[-grep( “A”, Text)]
[1] "B.txt" "C.txt"
```

However when I do this on Text2 all elements disappear in cyberspace.

```
> Text2[-grep( “A”, Text2)]
character(0)
```

How can I change the code so that it works on all vectors?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: thanks for all answers, they all work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at what `grep("A", Text2)` is actually returning:

```
grep("A", Text2)
# integer(0)
```

That is, it can't find 'A' in `Text2`. And therefore your `Text2[-integer(0)]` won't return anything

You can use `grepl` to test if the character exists (or doesn't exist in this case, using `!`)

```
Text[!grepl("A", Text)]
# [1] "B.txt" "C.txt"
Text2[!grepl("A", Text2)]
# [1] "B.txt" "C.txt"
```

---

Here, `grepl` returns a logical value if the character/pattern is matched. In this example for `Text2`, 'A' is not found in either element

```
grepl("A", Text2)
# [1] FALSE FALSE
```

So now we can 'negate' this, and subset the original vector, which is the same as going `Text2[!c(FALSE, FALSE)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `invert` parameter:

```
Text[grep("A", Text, fixed = TRUE, invert = TRUE)]
#[1] "B.txt" "C.txt"
Text2[grep("A", Text2, fixed = TRUE, invert = TRUE)]
#[1] "B.txt" "C.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to determine the indices in `Text2` which we do want to retain.  This is all indices which do *not* appear in the `grep` output.

```
Text2[!c(1:length(Text2)) %in% grep("A", Text2)]
```